# How to pass an object while routing to new view in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

In my application, I am opening a new page in a new tab when the user clicked on a button. This new page displays the data which it received from the previous page. I am able to retain the object data by setting the JSON model to the UI core or view if I use navTo() and don't load the view in a new tab. But, when I try to open the view in a new tab the model is getting destroyed.

Please, let me know if this can be achieved in UI5 and how.

Thanks in advance.

Venkatesh.

Comment: You don't. Routing is passing only keys. Data is located in a model. If, it's a JSON-Model it should be bound to the component.

Comment: In your `onRouteMatched` you should reload the data using the parameters that you passed to the router. This is not only important in your specific scenario but also when a user reloads a page the data has to be reloaded as well. Reloading a page and opening a page in a new tab is basically the same.